# Use CloudFormation to run a docker-compose present in an Ec2

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I have multiple Ec2 machines which contain docker compose file (they have the same pattern, its just one variable that is changed for each docker-compose file).
I can run only 2 ec2 machines at the same time due to rate limiting issue
So it was complete manual process to start 2 machines at one time and up the docker-compose,
see when the docker is exited and process is completed , I start the other machines (or even can delete the image of docker-compose and up it with different variable )

How can I automate this process, like how can I know when the ec2 machine is stopped (when docker is stopped),and start the other ec2 machine.
I was think of CloudFormation, but I am not aware how can we automate it completely.
Any idea is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

**cloud formation and load-balancer with autoscaling will help you more.**

- use autoscaling with load balancer and ec2 health check set with docker application.
  so you need to set EC2 health status with the docker health status.

1. set the docker-container application port is 8080(any docker application port) and check the health or status code of the application with the same port.
   Like:- /health and status code 200.
   So when ec2 health is checked with localhost:8080/health and the status code is 200 then ec2 works fine.
   but when the application goes down or the code is 404 then ec2 automatically goes down with autoscaling and runs up the new ec2 instance via autoscaling group.

Comment: Thanks for the answer
So one thing , the idea here is whenever docker its exited ,ec2 will go down with help of health check path
But when it spins up another ec2 it will have the same config (docker-compose file)
I want it to have a different docker-compose .